# Android app crash due to TimeoutException in Pre-launch reports of Google

Tags: android, android-espresso, google-play-console, prelaunch

I'm having an existing app on play store and today when I uploaded a new version of it after updating a string, I got a crash in Google Pre-launch reports which shows that there is TimeOutException in Espresso's default classes.

Error log is like:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
Process: com.example.app, PID: 23605
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Waited 10 seconds (plus 466517 nanoseconds delay) for androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.at.f@37bf20a[status=PENDING, info=[inputFuture=[androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.at.ad@d414a7b[status=PENDING]], function=[androidx.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction$3@fa06098]]]
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction$ExceptionPropagator.<init>(Web.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.doEval(Web.java:8)
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.perform(Web.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.HybridInteractionController.swipe(HybridInteractionController.java:15)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:45)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.ActionExecutor.performAction(ActionExecutor.java:4)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.handlePerformAction(RemotePlatform.java:22)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.messageLoop(RemotePlatform.java:59)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.lambda$startCrawlAndWaitUntilFinished$0$androidx-test-tools-crawler-platform-RemotePlatform(RemotePlatform.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Waited 10 seconds (plus 466517 nanoseconds delay) for androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.at.f@37bf20a[status=PENDING, info=[inputFuture=[androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.at.ad@d414a7b[status=PENDING]], function=[androidx.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction$3@fa06098]]]
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.at.a.get(AbstractFuture.java:50)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.at.m.get(FluentFuture.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction.get(AtomAction.java:4)
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.doEval(Web.java:6)
    ... 9 more
```

I have not updated Espresso test code since more than a year but still got this error. Could you please suggest me what I can do in this?

Comment: Maybe the changes in Android version over the past year is causing this behavior, is it possible for you to update the Espresso test code? Also, as a test case, it seems it's happening due to obfuscation process, maybe try to build the app for your own use with out obfuscating it and see if that's what really causes the issue?

Comment: I just checked the video in Pre-launch reports and found that Google's App review team clicked on a hyperlink in the web view at the end. That hyperlink opens a new webpage within app's web view.

Comment: I am also having the exact same issue, is there any update sir?

Comment: @BobTheCat This warning was coming due to some .js hyperlinks in webView so I added some code for handling timeout to prevent app from a crash.